# Resource id #13

Tags: php, mysql

Novice SQL & PHP user here, still learning.

Currently trying to complete a project for a friend, however, come across this error when trying to sum a column in SQL via php - Resource id #13.

```
PHP:
$uid = $user->data['id'];
//FETCH NUMBER OF SLOTS
$totalBookedSlots = $db->query( "SELECT COUNT(dj) FROM timetable WHERE dj='{$uid}' LIMIT 1" );
//TOTAL SLOTS ARRAY
$totalBookedSlots1 = mysql_result($totalBookedSlots,"totalBookedSlots");
```

...

```
<div class="box" style="width: 200px;">
    <div class="square title"><strong>Slots Booked</strong></div> 

         <p>You have <strong><?php echo $totalBookedSlots; ?></strong> slots booked!</div>

         <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

A

Comment: as you are still learning, it will be better to learn [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/pdo) instead of using the deprecated & removed `mysql_*` extension .

Comment: and how do you implement your `$db` object and `query` method ? or you are using mysqli or pdo already ?

Comment: Full page code here; https://pastebin.com/eVxRKF5n.

Comment: where is the `$db` object?

Comment: however, take a look at the `mysql_result` documentation page, specially the second parameter type.

Comment: This script is already completed, I'm just making some additions and modifications. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am voting close sorry. `$db->query` then mysql_result ? just no

Comment: @MichaelBerry Unfortunately, the code is really very wrong in its current form. One can't be mixing up object oriented (`$db->query`) and procedural (`mysql_*()`) ways for the same query. It'd rather be a good idea to rewrite the script from scratch using one of several tutorials available online. This randomly picked [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) demonstrates using PDO with Prepared Statements. As such, a script without Prepared Statements is very vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2298301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here.

1. You are mixing the deprecated MySQL extension with what appears to be MySQLi or PDO (whatever `$db` is). This won't work. You can't mix and match.

   (If `$db` is really based on the MySQL extension, *you need to fix this*. The MySQL extension has been removed **permanently** in PHP 7.0, which was released in late 2015. You need to be ready for this change.)
2. The value you're printing in your template is `$totalBookedSlots` -- the value you retrieved is in another variable, `$totalBookedSlots1`. (A better choice of variable names would have made this error much more obvious.)